# How to calculate Age Group wise US Population Data in Percentage

Tags: r

> I came across many Data Sets also Many Data Sets have constant age groups but I need below data table as output. You can consider any data set

| Age_Group | Percentage | Population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 60 Above Years | 20 | 74629409 |
| 50 - 59 Years | 10 | 42354542 |
| 40 - 49 Years | 10 | 40319374 |
| 30 - 39 Years | 15 | 44168826 |
| 19 - 29 Years | 15 | 45141956 |
| 0 - 18 Years | 30 | 81625416 |

Comment: try to start with `cut(x= sample(0:70, 10 ), breaks = c(0,18,29,49,59, 120))`  and replace x with your vector. Then, use the `table` or `aggregate` function or a dplyr group and summarize.

Comment: Thanks Roman, But My question is different

Comment: Aha...then you have to specify. So far as I can see you neither asked any question nor included enough information to extrapolate it in your post .

Comment: I already specify all the details in Question. I said the Output should be that table, mentioned in above question. 
And one more thing for this question you need to find dataset over internet and from that dataset I need required output table as mentioned in question

Comment: I understand your requirements, I have done something like this earlier, will share details with you soon, Thanks

Comment: @RShib Haha and you seriously think that I have the time to search data which is probably right for your needs in the tons of data available in the internet? Short answer: No. Update your question and meet the minimal requirements. Input, Output and code you have already worked with. My first comment contains the answer.  Feel free to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidycensus)

ageUS <- get_estimates(geography = "us", product = "characteristics", 
                       breakdown = c("AGEGROUP"),  
                       breakdown_labels = TRUE,
                       show_call = TRUE)

ageUS$AGEGROUP <- as.character(ageUS$AGEGROUP)

Age_Group <- c("60 and Above Years", "50 - 59 Years", "40 - 49 Years", 
"30 -39 Years", "19 - 29 Years", "0 - 18 Years")

Population_Split <- c(22, 09, 27, 25, 16, 16)
# Population_Of_Risk <- c(100, 88, 70, 60, 45, 17)

Input_Population_Split <- data.frame(Age_Group, Population_Split)

US_Population_Table <- select(Input_Population_Split, Age_Group)

US_Population_Table$Percentage <- ""
US_Population_Table$Population <- ""

Total_US_Population <- ageUS[1,3]

listAG <- c("Age 60 to 64 years", "Age 65 to 69 years", "Age 70 to 74 years", 
"Age 75 to 79 years", "Age 80 to 84 years", "Age 85 years and older")

AboveAG <- filter(ageUS, AGEGROUP %in% listAG) 

US_Population_Table[1,2] <- round((sum(AboveAG$value) / Total_US_Population) * 100, 2)

US_Population_Table[1,3] <- sum(AboveAG$value)

listAG <- c("Age 50 to 54 years", "Age 55 to 59 years")

AboveAG <- filter(ageUS, AGEGROUP %in% listAG) 

US_Population_Table[2,2] <- round((sum(AboveAG$value) / Total_US_Population) * 100, 2)

US_Population_Table[2,3] <- sum(AboveAG$value)

listAG <- c("Age 40 to 44 years", "Age 45 to 49 years")

AboveAG <- filter(ageUS, AGEGROUP %in% listAG) 

US_Population_Table[3,2] <- round((sum(AboveAG$value) / Total_US_Population) * 100, 2)

US_Population_Table[3,3] <- sum(AboveAG$value)

listAG <- c("Age 30 to 34 years", "Age 35 to 39 years")

AboveAG <- filter(ageUS, AGEGROUP %in% listAG) 

US_Population_Table[4,2] <- round((sum(AboveAG$value) / Total_US_Population) * 100, 2)

US_Population_Table[4,3] <- sum(AboveAG$value)

listAG <- c("Age 20 to 24 years", "Age 25 to 29 years")

AboveAG <- filter(ageUS, AGEGROUP %in% listAG) 

US_Population_Table[5,2] <- round((sum(AboveAG$value) / Total_US_Population) * 100, 2)

US_Population_Table[5,3] <- sum(AboveAG$value)

listAG <- c("Age 0 to 4 years", "Age 5 to 9 years", "Age 10 to 14 years", 
"Age 15 to 19 years")

# listAG <- c("Under 18 years")

AboveAG <- filter(ageUS, AGEGROUP %in% listAG) 

US_Population_Table[6,2] <- round((sum(AboveAG$value) / Total_US_Population) * 100, 2)

US_Population_Table[6,3] <- sum(AboveAG$value)

US_Population_Table$Percentage <- as.numeric(US_Population_Table$Percentage)

US_Population_Table$Population <- as.numeric(US_Population_Table$Population)

view(US_Population_Table)

Age_Group             Percentage    Population
60 and Above Years    22.74         74629409
50 - 59 Years         12.90         42354542
40 - 49 Years         12.28         40319374
30 - 39 Years         13.46         44168826
19 - 29 Years         13.75         45141956
0 - 18 Years          24.87         81625416
```

Comment: Thanks Man This was best solution @maheshkulkarni